# How to know if Text to speech is in progress?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, android-developer-api

While using Text-To-Speech , how can we know if text to speech is in progress or not ? Progress mean it is converting text to voice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to check if tts is in progress or not

```
  if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
                    ///your code
                }
```